# ¿Cómo habilitar y deshabilitar un ConfirmButton de un swal2, a travez de un checkbox?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

Estoy empezando a trabajar con los sweetAlert2 y estoy tratando de habilitar y deshabilitar un ConfirmButton a travez de un checkbox que esta antes, esto es lo que he intentado:

```
swal.fire({
            title: "¿Enviar formulario?",
            input: 'checkbox',
            inputPlaceholder: "Acepto que la toda información sea enviada.",
            icon: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            confirmButtonText: 'Si, confirmar',
            cancelButtonText: 'No, cancelar!',
            reverseButtons: true,
            onOpen: function (){
                swal2.disableConfirmButton();
                     },
        /* }, function(){ 
            $('.swal2-confirm').on('change', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                val = this.checked;
                if (val) {
                    $(".swal2-confirm").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
                }else{
                    $(".swal2-confirm").attr('disabled', false); 
                }
            }) */
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                if (resultAjax == true) {
                    Swal.fire(
                        dataPreregistro.data.message,
                        '',
                        'success'
                    )
                } else {
                    Swal.fire(
                        'Error:',
                        dataPreregistro.data.responseJSON.errors_msgs,
                        'error'
                    )
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

Cómo tal estoy tratando de que la alerta lance deshabilitado el confirmButtton y yo acepte el uso de la información a travez de un checkbox y una vez que yo marque el checkbox se habilite el boton de confirmar.

Gracias por leerme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Qué tal?
La lógica que se enseñas al tener el modal abierto es buena, pero debido a que `OnOpen` está obsoleto en SA2 y pasa a ser: `didOpen`, no podrías acceder a esa función. Agrego que no es necesario usar selectores para obtener el botón ya que es posible usar métodos propios de la librería sweet para simplificar esto.

`didOpen():` Se ejecuta de forma asincrónica después de que se haya mostrado la ventana emergente en la pantalla.

`getConfirmButton():` Obtiene el botón confirmar.

`getInput():` Obtiene el nodo DOM de entrada.

```
//El modal se ejecuta con un botón para que pueda verlo enseguida
    document.getElementById("boton")
    .addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
      e.preventDefault()
      Swal.fire({
        input: 'checkbox',
        showCancelButton:true,
        didOpen: () =>{
          Swal.getConfirmButton().disabled = true
          Swal.getInput().addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            if(this.checked) {
              Swal.getConfirmButton().disabled = false
            } else {
              Swal.getConfirmButton().disabled = true
            }
          }) 
        }
      });
    })
```

Al mostrarse en pantalla el modal, didOpen() deshabilita el botón de confirmar usando getConfirmButton() y se aplica en false su atributo *disabled*. Luego usando getInput() se puede obtener el valor del checkbox en el modal para realizar la validación usando el eventListener change + getConfirmButton() dependiendo del estado del checkbox.